# Using a hyperlink to a Thumbs up if 100% is achieved. Or if not a thumbs down

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a progress chart where each week participants record a number in one cell and the next cell automatically converts that number to a percentage of the progress made, as in the mock up below:

| name | week_1 | week_1_perc | week_2 | week_2_perc | week_3 | week_3_perc | week_4 | week_4_perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | 0 | 0.0% | 17 | 9.7% | 128 | 72.7% | 176 | 100.0% |
| Bob | 57 | 32.4% | 71 | 40.3% | 96 | 54.5% | 124 | 70.5% |
| Bill | 1 | 0.6% | 3 | 1.7% | 74 | 42.0% | 113 | 64.2% |
| Brad | 0 | 0.0% | 19 | 10.8% | 42 | 23.9% | 160 | 90.9% |
| Brian | 130 | 73.9% | 152 | 86.4% | 176 | 100.0% | 176 | 100.0% |

I need to add some fun into this task so I'd like to add another cell that says "Click to check progress".
Then only when the formular can see a 100% it will open a hyperlink to a Thumbs Up icon and a message pops up with "Fantastic You Have Finished".
But if there is not a 100% in their row then when the cell is clicked, the hyperlink is to a Thumbs Down icon and a message "Your nearly there keep going."

I have tried this but it is not even valid. Plus others and nothing works.

```
=IF($D$11:$J$11="*100", HYPERLINK("#$$D$11:$J$11", "Click here to check progress"), "#"&$D$11:$J$11)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to superuser! Good to see that you've attempted some things already, but it would be nice if you could also show what you've researched so far. Have you looked at the [HYPERLINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) page to see how it is supposed to work? Have you looked at other resources that show how a message can be displayed in Excel? If so, please [edit] your question to include what you've found and what remained uncelar, this allows everyone to provide better help.

Comment: Beyond getting `HYPERLINK` to work, it doesn't seem like the logical test part of the `IF()` formula would even work or rather I suspect it almost always returns false (depending whatever `$D11` is referencing).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . I'll follow up the advice given and see if I can find a solution. My other idea was to have a different message pop up when the button or cell is clicked. For example at 25, 50 75 and 100% increasing encouragement messages appear. That may be esier than a Hyperlink.